# Problem with relative layouts: anchored elements at the top right

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create an android application but I'm a beginner, especially with the XML. I don't know why, if I put Relative layout and move the widgets they remain anchored at the top left. does anyone know why?

ps I would like to work on the window design not on the code. Anyway I leave you the code in case there is something wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".Tentativo">

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Number"

        android:textSize="50dp"

        android:textStyle="bold"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.255"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/button"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Play"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="247dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="211dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The attributes that you are using, such as `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf`, are for `ConstraintLayout`, not `RelativeLayout`. I strongly recommend that you switch to using `ConstraintLayout`, as the tools and up-to-date educational materials will be focusing on `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I changed from costrain to relative but remain anchored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this problem because you are using the wrong attributes. The attributes you are using are meant for Constraint Layout and not Relative layout.

For Example: in case of TextView instead of using `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` try using  `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Also, I would like to recommend you to use Constraint Layout instead of Relative as is much better and easier to use. example: To center a view in a RelativeLayout you would write `centerInParent=true`. Constraint Layout instead allows centering in-between views and the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`relative layout` works great with nested sibling Containers, just add a container, and add the Widgets inside the container, my favorite one to use when `Relative Layout` is the parent is the `Linear Layout`, it makes the UI much cleaner and  uses weights which is great for supporting different screen ratios. Here is a sample Example for your case (also you can remove all the constraints in the widget since their parent is no longer the relative layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="Number"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:textSize="50dp"

            android:textStyle="bold"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.255"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.299" />

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/button"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:text="Play"

            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="247dp"

            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="211dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```